# Steam Chat completely dropping messages

Tags: steam

For some reason whenever I close the lid of my laptop(lenovo T540p), sleep, logoff or shutdown. steam chat will stop receiving messages completely, and will never show up in the chat. This is odd because my old laptop would always receive every message, even when I went offline and turned off my computer I would at least see all the messages I missed when I logged back on.
I know this is happening because the steam app picks up all the messages just fine. but it is rather frustrating to have to keep logging into steam on my phone just to see everything.
any suggestions?

Comment: Contact Steam support for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you could really do here is to contact steam support. This is an application level bug, this isn't something to do with your own PC or your installation.